# Ubuntu 15.10 and Google Chrome- drag and drop off by a screen.

Tags: nvidia, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I'm running 15.10 with three monitors using NVidia's proprietary drivers and xinerama. When I open chrome, click and drag to move the chrome window has the chrome window appear a full screen and a half to the right of my mouse. Dragging shortcuts also does this, leading to random desktop .URL files whenever I inevitably forget and try to bookmark a page.
Has anyone seen this issue/have a potential fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Ah; found the issue and fixed it. Apparantly, my Nvidia settings wasn't recognizing my SLI, and was forcing me to use Xinerama and a single X Screen on each monitor, instead of a single X screen spread across three monitors, and apparantly this was causing issues.
Modifying my X config file manually to be very similar to https://www.martineve.com/2014/04/15/enabling-a-triple-head-3-monitor-setup-on-linux-mint-16-petra-with-two-nvidia-cards/ has corrected everything.